# selenium chrome webdriver cannot access my local port

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

```
# -*- coding:utf-8-*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

def makeScreenShot():
    url = 'http://11.111.111.11:3000/'
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
    driver.get(string_url)
    driver.save_screenshot('my.png')
    driver.quit()
```

i want to save a screenshot of my server 
but i can't access to my server

I also tried this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-rowser/chromedriver',port=3000)
```

but it does't work

And another problem is that the Korean language is broken.
 [image]

That's the placeholder of input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-core
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-unfonts-extra
```

The second problem was solved by the above command.